# I need assistance in updating my footer to be bottom fixed without overlapping my left hand nav bar

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, blazor, footer

I've read the different posts here asking for footer help; but unfortunately I do not see anything here that have worked in assisting me.

I am building a web app where I am trying to fix the footer to the bottom of the page without overlapping my nav bar (Orange bar) on the left hand side.

Currently my page and code are:

[fixed bottom, overlapping nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPphj.png)

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="HeaderBar row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <img src="images/systemslogo.png" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="FeatureBar row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <p>Welcome</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row min-vh-100">
            <div class="navbar col-md-1" style="background-color: #f78a00;">

            </div>
            <div class="col-md-11">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <AlertSuccess/>
                        @Body
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row fixed-bottom" style="background-color: #CCCCCC;"> 
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <p>Footer</p>
                    </div>
                </div>                
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

If I remove the "fixd-bottom"; the footers width fixes; but then the footer floats to the top of the page like so:

[Floating footer proper width](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GBYvG.jpg)

I have also attached my end goal image; I have blocked out the personal content.
[End Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3dwA.jpg)
I have tried:

1. Position relative with Bottom 0
2. margin left (although moves footer over; it screws up when looking at mobile view where there should be no margin. (wasn't sure if I should do a media query and use this option)
3. Position Absolute with mb-0
4. Other ideas, but cannot recall
   what I have tried.

I am building this app in Blazor with Bootstrap 4.5.2

Thanks everyone for the assistance. I've been googling and trying for past 2 hours with on success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for `position: fixed;`

> An element with position: fixed; is positioned relative to the
> viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the
> page is scrolled. The top, right, bottom, and left properties are used
> to position the element.
>
> A fixed element does not leave a gap in the page where it would
> normally have been located.

*Source @ https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp*

Comment: Thanks; that helped me in identifying what I was doing wrong. Part of my issue was too many rows inside rows I believe. I don't think I was doing that right in my logical thought.